# How to uninstall Wolfram CDF Player on Linux?

Tags: installation, cdfplayer

I have version 11 and I need the space for something else. It would have been easier to do if a deb package was available for it, since you can uninstall software installed in such a way by starting the installer again.

Comment: I assume it is analogous to [uninstalling Mathematica](https://support.wolfram.com/kb/12473) and that you need to remove the files manually.

Comment: @Szabolcs The links that answers to this question point to are no longer valid.

Comment: https://support.wolfram.com/12473 might work better